# AppleCare - Can I Cancel The Monthly Plan After Doing a Repair?

Tags: iphone, repair, applecare

If I get AppleCare today and pay $7.99 a month for coverage on my iPhone and then do a screen replacement next month, would I then be able to cancel the monthly subscription the month afterwards?

I know that with the $149 upfront plan, you won’t get a refund for discounts / services you’ve already received.  Would the scenario I described above be allowed?

Comment: AppleCare screen replacement doesn't cover accidental damage, only a fault. If it was a manufacturing defect, you wouldn't need AppleCare anyway, under EU law [idk about other jurisdictions.] Basically, if you dropped it, you need insurance, not AppleCare.

Answer (score 1):

Most products are covered by AppleCare+ these days, so you would need to read the terms and conditions for your specific region where you purchased it to be sure.

- https://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/applecare/applecareplus/

In the US you can cancel the monthly iPhone (and most other iOS/watchOS product) plan at any time for any reason.

> 8.2 Monthly Pay Plans
>
> You may cancel this Plan at any time for any reason.

It then spells out the details on how to cancel and what happens when you do.